# Make binary executable for all users

Tags: linux, permissions, users

Let say I have flutter binary at `~/flutter/bin/flutter` with execute permission for user,group and others. I want to make binary accessible or executable for all the users in system.

Since the binary already have the executable permission for others,

Is making binary executable from anywhere makes every users to access it ? If so where do I set the PATH to make it executable from anywhere? Does setting `PATH=$PATH:/home/username/flutter/bin` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` then doing `source /etc/bash.bashrc` solves ?

I know people set `PATH=$PATH:~/flutter/bin` in `~/.bashrc`. But this makes binary executable only for the user, right ?

What is the difference in setting PATH in `/etc/environment` and setting in `/etc/bash.bashrc` ?

What about the below mentioned other approaches ?

1. Copy `~/flutter/*` to `/opt/` then set `PATH=$PATH:/opt/flutter/bin` in `/etc/bash.bashrc`
2. Create a symlink from `~/flutter/bin/flutter` to `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` or to any of the path mentioned in the PATH variable.

Comment: Putting the file in a some general location (like `/opt` or `/usr/local`) would likely be cleaner than having it in a single user's home directory. Especially since executing the file will require access permission to all directories in the path to it, and you might not want users to be able to access other users' homes in general. Symlinks don't change it, it's the real location of the file that counts.

Comment: All the suggested solutions would work.  Differences are in effort, cleanness , and fragility.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work and can be modified if needed:

1. If it's the binary and nothing else, copy it to `/usr/local/bin` which is in the default `PATH` for Linux and most Unix-like operating systems.
2. Copy it to `/opt` (or build it there if necessary) and then:

   export PATH=/opt/flutter/bin:$PATH

If this is a common Linux distro such as Fedora/Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives, Arch, etc then a file can be created in `/etc/profile.d/flutter.sh` with the above as the contents (or whatever name is desired ending in `.sh` so that in `bash`, it will source file and login and add the directory to the path for everyone. That is only sourced at login as are `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`, etc. If adding that directory to the PATH when starting a new shell session is wanted, then it will have to be added to the user's shell init script such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.kshrc`, etc.

You can reverse the order if you want but I have it that way to make sure that it finds the `flutter` binary in that directory first in case it is located elsewhere. Also, it has the full path to the directory where the file is located and not the full path to the binary itself.

You don't want to store it in a users's home directory as accessing it will require adding execute bits on the home directory for users which will render it accessible to everyone which probably isn't wanted as the default mask is 022 unless it was changed and/or the permission bits for users were removed. That's is why I advise placing it elsewhere. A link would require the same.

Comment: @ChrisDavies That's correct, but that would still effectively render all of the data in the user's directory accessible in most cases as the default 022 mask is normally in effect with sets all of the permissions as 755 for directories and 644 for files inside of user home directories. I edited that part of the answer to cover this.